# How to override role's file on Ansible?

Tags: provisioning, ansible

I am using the [zzet.rbenv role](https://github.com/zzet/ansible-rbenv-role) on my playbook. It has a `files/default-gems` file that it copies to the provisioned system.

I need my playbook to check for a `myplaybook/files/default-gems` and use it *if it exists*, using the `zzet.rbenv/files/default-gems` if otherwise.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research and trial/error. I found out that Ansible is not capable of checking if files exist between roles. This is due to the way role dependencies (which roles themselves) will get expanded into the one requiring it, making it part of the playbook. There are no tasks that will let you differentiate `my_role/files/my_file.txt` from `required_role/files/my_file.txt`.

One approach to the problem (the one I found the easiest and cleanest) was to:

1. Add a variable to the `my_role` with the path to the file I want to use (overriding the default one)
2. Add a task (identical to the one that uses the default file) that checks if the above variable is defined and run the task using it

**Example**

required_role

```
# Existing task
- name: some task
  copy: src=roles_file.txt dest=some/directory/file.txt
  when: my_file_path is not defined

# My custom task
- name: my custom task (an alteration of the above task)
  copy: src={{ my_file_path }} dest=/some/directory/file.txt
  when: my_file_path is defined
```

my_role

```
#... existing code 
my_file_path: "path/to/my/file"
```

---

As mentioned by *Ramon de la Fuente*: this solution was accepted into the [zzet.rbenv repo](https://github.com/andradei/ansible-rbenv-role/commit/434602710d8dbd047ad70f24cdc950971a0bdafc) :)

Comment: This works, but it would be a problem if where where tasks in the role you're depending on use the file also. Your solution is a solid one, but I'd recommend sending a pull-request to the role owner so that the original role can have the variable path name. It makes for more flexible galaxy roles that way.

Comment: Oh, I see the role supports this now: https://github.com/andradei/ansible-rbenv-role/commit/434602710d8dbd047ad70f24cdc950971a0bdafc Nice :-)